# preventing a child from inheriting draggable" attribute in html

Tags: html, inheritance, draggable

i have some `<div></div>` elements with `draggable="true"` attribute but same thing gets applied on child elements,but i dont want to apply it on child elements, So how do i prevent this default behavior?

code :

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="play(event)" ondrop="pause(event)" id="move">
    <span id="text">
        drag me
    </span>
</div>
```

as i used `dragable="true"` on `<div>` so span also gets the same property.

Comment: post your code please, we can't help you otherwise

Comment: set draggable false on the child. If it works anything like contenteditable that may work. Or else, make sure on your events, you drop and drag only the parent data. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar event with a sortable drag-and-drop "list" I created. Each "row" of the list looks like this.

```
<div class='row' draggable='true'>
    <div class='drag-handle' ></div>
    <img class='icon-image' draggable='false'>
    <input type='text' name='demo' >
    <button class='remove-btn' onclick='removeItem(this,event)'>Remove</button>
</div>
```

When I tried selecting the text inside of the "input" element, somehow I would start dragging the whole "row". As frustrating as this was, the best solution I found was to simply apply the `draggable='true'` property to the item with the `class="drag-handle"` which would be my dragging icon that would fire the `ondragstart(e)` event.

**The rest can be handled in JS**

In JS, reference the parent element "row" by using the `closest(".row")` method

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    document.querySelectorAll('.drag-handle').forEach(handle => {
        handle.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart)
        handle.addEventListener("drag", dragging)
        handle.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd)

    })



    function dragStart(e) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".row").forEach(row=>{
            row.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver)
        })
    
        var target_row = e.target.closest(".row")
    target_row.classList.add("dragging")

}
```

**Note**:
I added a class of "dragging" to the one "row" that was going to be dragged so I could do a `querySelectorAll('.row:not(.dragging)')` for other operations, classes, etc, however, this is NOT required for the intended purpose to work. Just a bit more context that hope helps your problem.